# My function is not showing .It is showing error

Tags: r

A very useful feature in R is the ability to pass a function name as an argument.
Here is an example, where 2 is added to the value of a function, for three different functions `$exp(x)$`, `$log(x)$`, and `$sin(x)$`, at selected points `$x$`.

```
{r}
test=function(x,f){
    output=f(x)+2
    return(output)
}

test(0,exp)
test(1,log)
test(0,sin)
test(pi/2,sin)
```

I need to modify my function for the below question so that you pass in the name of the function for which you want to approximate the derivative. Use the same default value for $h$, and approximate the derivative of `sin(x)` at `$x=\pi/4$`, of `$log(x)$` at `$x=2$`, and of `$exp(x)$` at `$x=1$`.

**The question is:**
The derivative of a function $f(x)$ can be approximated by the Newton's quotient

```
$$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$
```

where `$h$` is a small number.  Write a function to calculate the Newton's quotient for `$f(x) = exp(x)$`.  The function should take two scalar arguments, `$x$` and `$h$`.
Use a default value of $h=1.e-6$.

Test your function at the point `$x=1$` using the default value of `$h$`, and compare to the true value of the derivative `$f'(1) = e^1$`.

Now I wrote the code as

```
test=function(x,h,f){
    a=f(x+h)
    b=f(x)
    d=a-b
    g=d/h
    return (g)
}

test(sin,pi/4)
```

However it shows the error as

```
Error in f(x + h) : argument "f" is missing, with no default
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Your `test` function has three arguments but you are providing just two. Mind the correct order of your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this and modify according what you need (I added both functions you included in the question):

```
test<-function(x,f){
  output<-eval(parse(text=f(x)))+2
  return(output)
}

test<-function(x,f,h=1.e-6){
  a<-eval(parse(text=f(x+h)))
  b<-eval(parse(text=f(x)))
  d<-a-b
  g<-d/h
  return (g)
}

test(f = sin,x = pi/4)
```

Comment: Why all this `eval(parse())`? What's wrong with `a <- f(x + h)`?